# 404 Not Found Show File in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, symlink

I've created a symbolic link to access files in storage/app/public/uploads. but when I call it through the browser the file is not found.

I've also configured config/filesystems.php as shown
[image]

Comment: What is the file path you're getting in browser? Can you please check and share the path?

Comment: "https://domain/public/storage/uploads/file.mp4"

Comment: Is your `storage` folder in `public` folder?

Comment: in `storage` folder. for the details of the folder storage/app/public/uploads

Comment: try to run `php artisan storage:link` or check folder path if it is correct as per directory.

Comment: i have solved this case. files must be kept in `public/storage/uploads`. but when I run the script to upload, the file is stored in `storage/app/public/uploads`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel docs, your publicly accessible files should be put in directory

```
storage/app/public
```

To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

```
domain/storage/app/public/uploads/file.mp4
```

Now you can create in your view an URL to the files using the asset helper:

```
echo asset('storage/file.mp4');
```

Comment: I've run that. but still not found

Comment: can you show us how you are accessing the file

Comment: i have solved this case. files must be kept in `public/storage/uploads`. but when I run the script to upload, the file is stored in `storage/app/public/uploads`